# What happens when we modify access to a file from read to inaccessible for a process when that process is already accessing it?

Tags: android

Lets take 2 processes P1 and P2. P1 grants permission to P2 to open file F1, which is in its sandbox. While P2 reads F1, P1 may revoke P2's permission to read F1. Would P2 be able to still read F1? Since P2 has already opened the file when it had the permission to.

Comment: If file is still open yes, if not no

Comment: Could you please explain when the permission checks do happen during file access? Apart from the 'open' call. It would be informative.

Comment: as far as i know when you try to open a file it checks the permission that you have or not. If you don't then you can't open it. When you open and edit it, it will check the write permission when you are trying to save. Otherwise no checks happen (as far as i know)